# VideoView seekTo 0 instead of specific position

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-videoview, seek

I'm trying to start video from specific position but VideoView has strange behave. When I run code like that

```
videoView.seekTo(2000)
int current = videoView.getCurrentPosition()
Log.e("Current Time", String.valueOf(current))
```

Log gives me value 0. It should give 2000 because this is current position. Even If I implement onPreparedListener it doesn't worked (but in different way). It display proper value (2000) but video still is not seek.

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                videoView.getDuration();
                videoView.seekTo(2000);
                Log.e("Current: ", String.valueOf(videoView.getCurrentPosition()));
            }
        });
```

How to fight this ? If I will build MediaPlayer + SurfaceView it will helps or will behave same as VideoView ?

Comment: Have you checked if seekTo is possible at all: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#canSeekForward()

Comment: Hmm, regular MediaPlayer class provides a callback `OnSeekCompleteListener`, but it looks like VideoView is not offering callbacks. I guess going for an own implementation might be the better solution. Or consider e.g. using Exoplayer?

Comment: @Christopher you it can be seek.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the thing is,VideoView.seekTo() is a wrapper around MediaPlayer.seekTo(). This function returns almost immediately even though the actual seeking is still being performed. Therefore you want to wait for seeking to complete via ***MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener***.

However, the standard VideoView does not support ***OnSeekCompleteListener***.

***But you can copy and locally customize the VideoView class to add this support yourself.***

***Or, You could try this***

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer .OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {


            Log.e("Current: ", String.valueOf(videoView.getCurrentPosition()));
        }
    });

}
});
videoView.seekTo(2000); //or wherever the call is to be made
```

Hope this should help.

Comment: I read it before :D anyway it doesn't explain this strange behaviour.

Comment: You can, however, use the OnSeekCompleteListener via the media player object.I have added that code, hope it helps.

Comment: I will try it in minutes

Comment: Code didn't even get called.

Comment: What problem did you have exactly? Could you please elaborate?
The thing here is, you have to call the OnSeekCompleteListener from inside your OnPreparedListener, as videoview do not have SeekCompleteListener.

Comment: First of all, we need to call videoView.seekTo before onPreparedListener if OnSeekComplete want to be called. If we do that log give us proper value (2000) but thing is that video still start from the begining.